# How to navigate a 1d array in a 2d manner?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I've got this sample code below. I understand cells is being made in a 1 dimensional manner,
since the compiler stores 2d arrays in memory row-by-row in 1d. What I don't understand/can't visualize is how to access elements or change positions.

1. I know `board->cells[i + (20 * (10 - 1))] = FLAG_WALL;`  is used to set flags for the bottom most row. From the format it looks to be using a formula but I am unsure of what it is. The formula also seems to change for the right and left edges.
   (`board->cells[i * 20 + 20 - 1] = FLAG_WALL;`)
2. Looking at the line `board->cells[20 * 2 + 2] = FLAG_SNAKE;` it seems cell[42] is where the snake flag is spawned. What would the arithmetic look like to shift its position by 1 cell up, down, right, left? When imagining cell[42] as a part of a 1d array in memory I can't figure out the arithmetic nor the resulting cell number after a shift such as 'up'.

```
board_init_status_t initialize_default_board(board_t* board) {
    board->width = 20;
    board->height = 10;
    board->cells = calloc(20 * 10, sizeof(int));

    // Set edge cells!
    // Top and bottom edges:
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        board->cells[i] = FLAG_WALL;
        board->cells[i + (20 * (10 - 1))] = FLAG_WALL;
    }
    // Left and right edges:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        board->cells[i * 20] = FLAG_WALL;
        board->cells[i * 20 + 20 - 1] = FLAG_WALL;
    }

    // Add snake
    board->cells[20 * 2 + 2] = FLAG_SNAKE;

    return INIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 1 cell up, if we think with (x;y) coordinates that would be y + 1 ?

Comment: It's `cells[x + width * y]`.

Comment: @Jules If through (x, y) coordinates 1 up would shift snakes position from (2, 3) to (2,4). But I am trying to understand from a non-coordinate 1d perspective

Comment: @HolyBlackCat for the top and bottom edges? Or in general?

Comment: In general. Substitute `width=20`, then try subsituting one of: `y=0`, `y=10-1`, `x=0`, `x = 20-1`, and you'll arrive at the 4 formulas used in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Think of the 1d array as a 2d one, the beginning of the last row would be at the position `width * (height - 1)` and the last cell of the last row at `width * height` almost the same logic goes for the sides.
2. `board->cells[20 * 2 + 2] = FLAG_SNAKE;` means it goes at the 2nd row in position 2. Or in (x;y) coordinates (2, 2). It's pure math. If you want to move in a 1d array like in a 2d one just multiply the length of one line by the index of the row you want to go (let's call it `y`) and then add `x` to reach the `x` cell.

```
board_init_status_t initialize_default_board(board_t* board) {
    board->width = 20;
    board->height = 10;
    board->cells = calloc(20 * 10, sizeof(int));

    // Set edge cells!
    // Top and bottom edges:
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        board->cells[i] = FLAG_WALL; // [0, 19] (top row)
        board->cells[i + (20 * (10 - 1))] = FLAG_WALL; // [180, 199] (bottom row)
    }
    // Left and right edges:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        board->cells[i * 20] = FLAG_WALL; // (left row)
        board->cells[i * 20 + 20 - 1] = FLAG_WALL; // (right row)
    }

    // Add snake
    board->cells[20 * 2 + 2] = FLAG_SNAKE;

    return INIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Okay so I understand most of it now, navigating a 1d array in a 2d way is just cells[(num of columns * y) + x]. This is calculating the position of cells you want to travel to. What I am still shaky is how you would shift locations from a predetermined point. 

Specific example: Take cells[20 * 2 + 2] or cells[42]as the starting point. This should be second row position 2 from what you said. So If I wanted to shift up the new position should be first row position 2. How could I calculate the cell number of this new position?

Comment: To boil it down: given only cells[37]and told to shift up. How could I calculate the index of the new position?

Comment: Use the formula you gave in the previous comment. cells[num_of_columns * y + x]. So cell[37] is cell[20 * 3 + 7]. To shift it up it's just cell[20 * 2 + 7].